# Remove everything from a string except . and numbers through 0-9 - Java

Tags: java, regex, numbers, replaceall

I am trying to read a line of text and remove everything besides periods and numbers through 0 - 9.

This is what I am trying but It removes everything except spaces.

```
distance.replaceAll("[^0-9 + \\.]", "");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A literal `.` is `.` (and an escape is `\\` not one `\`), and you can use `\\d` for digits. Like,

```
String distance = "123zz.0";
System.out.println(distance.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", ""));
```

Outputs (as requested)

```
123.0
```

Comment: Do you need to escape the `.` when it's in character class? I try without and it works fine.

Comment: `.` is not a special character inside a character class. And you can get a *very* small performance boost by adding `+` after the character class. Also, since you have the character class anyway, `\\d` is no better than `0-9`, since they are both 3 characters long. Ok, I'll stop nitpicking now.

Comment: @AntonH Good point. OP had `\.` in the original. And that threw me.

Comment: You can also approach it in the opposite way, and instead of removing, take what you want and call a join on the results. I'm not sure how that'd work in java, but in javascript it'd be `"123.xx.sdfk234".match(/(\d|\.)+/g).join("")`

Comment: I'm not sure either but the answer works well enough. Thank you to all who helped.